# How does OSGi application work on Java 9?

Tags: java, osgi, java-9

I am trying to understand how OSGi application works in Java 9 assuming that OSGi bundle is not JPMS module (as far as I know there is still no solution that OSGi bundle could be at the same time JPMS module for production). And I have several questions:

1. Do I understand right that all OSGi application will be one unnamed module?
2. If #1 yes, then how does `Bundle.update()` works? Is bundle reloaded to unnamed module?

If I understand everything wrong, please explain main principles.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Java SE 9 guarantees continued compatibility for all applications and libraries that stick to the standard Java SE libraries.

OSGi only uses published Java SE APIs and therefore will continue to work unchanged on Java 9. It does not at this time interact with JPMS modules, which will be the case for all your other Java software. At some point the OSGi expert groups will likely produce a specification for interoperability between JPMS modules and OSGi bundles, but that is for the future.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Yes, OSGi bundles will be mapped to one or more "unnamed" modules in JPMS terms. Again, this is exactly how Java 9 retains backwards compatibility for all your other Java applications.
2. Bundle update works the same way it has worked for 18 years. The classloader provided for the bundle is disposed and a new classloader created to load the updates classes.

Comment: FYI, the proposal for JPMS in [JSR 376](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=376) explicitly acknowledged the value of OSGi, and stated its intention for OSGi to continue working under Java 9. To quote section 2.5: *OSGi’s life-cycle and dynamic service-registry facilities are useful to some kinds of sophisticated applications but are beyond the scope of the needs outlined above. Those who require these facilities will still be able to run OSGi on top of Java SE 9 implementations.*

Answer (score 8):

OSGi uses class loaders to isolate bundles and continues to do so on Java 9. Since each JAR is loaded by a separate class loader, each ends up in its own unnamed module. That means OSGi effectively ignores the JPMS and continues to work just as before Java 9.